# Expose Rails Env to Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript, webpack

I'm running Rails v5 with Webpacker v2. Everything's been smooth so far, but I've hit one hiccup: how to expose Rails helpers to my TypeScript.

I know Webpacker ships with rails-erb-loader, so I was expecting that I'd be able to add `.erb` to a TypeScript file, and then import that file elsewhere:

```
// app/javascript/utils/rails.ts.erb
export const env = "<%= Rails.env %>"

export function isEnv(envName: string) {
  return env == envName
}

// app/javascript/packs/application.ts
import { env } from "../utils/rails"
```

But Webpack can't find the "rails" file even if I modify the typescript loader to include ERB files:

```
module.exports = {
  test: /.ts(\.erb)?$/,
  loader: 'ts-loader'
}
```

All I see is:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '../utils/rails'.
```

What's the best way to go about exposing Rails helpers and variables to my JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails env comes from your environment variable. This means you configure it by setting (in bash for example) the variable in this way:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

As a consequence, you don't need to deal with Rails at all.

```
// app/javascript/utils/rails.ts.erb
export const env = process.env.RAILS_ENV || "development"

export function isEnv(envName: string) {
  return env == envName
}
```

This comes with a great advantage: **you don't have to load the whole rails app just to compile your javascript**. Rails can become really slow on first load if your app grows.

Since you won't have access to `process.env` on the frontend (browser), you also need a way to make it *exist*. In webpack, this is done through the [`DefinePlugin`](https://gist.github.com/haf/f671f1113d2c5dead5a7#file-gistfile1-txt-L109-L113):

Update your webpack configuration to use the plugin (in `plugins` section): `new webpack.DefinePlugin({ "process.env": { RAILS_ENV: process.env.RAILS_ENV } })` and you will get a `process.env.RAILS_ENV` available in the client

Comment: You're onto something... but web clients can't access `process.env` (VM265:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined) Maybe there's some way to preprocess that?

Comment: You said webpacker, so I assumed you are talking about nodejs. If that's the case, update your webpack configuration to use the plugin `DefinePlugin` ( https://gist.github.com/haf/f671f1113d2c5dead5a7#file-gistfile1-txt-L109-L113 ), with something like `new webpack.DefinePlugin({ "process.env": { RAILS_ENV: process.env.RAILS_ENV } })` and you will get a `process.env.RAILS_ENV` available in the client

Comment: Perfect! Can you update your answer with that for posterity's sake?

Comment: Yes! Done, hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Rails Env can be accessed through:

```
process.env.RAILS_ENV
```

Comment: You'll see in your `config/webpack` directory that each environment sets a correct `process.env.NODE_ENV` that you can use also.